# How to add popup message in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have 1 problem..I had to do drag n drop an image..then get the position of image after drop...Then, when I drag it and get the position, I need to display a pop up message using jquery..Can anyone help me? Please show me the demo and clear solution because Im new in jquery..Thank you guys!!

This is my code of dra,drop n get coordinate..now , I want to add the pop up message after get the position..In the pop up message, I want to add -->name your location and can be saved in database.

This is my code:

```
     $('#dragThis').draggable({
    cursor: 'move',        // sets the cursor apperance
    containment: '#dragThis2',
    drag: function() {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var xPos = Math.abs(offset.left);
    var yPos = Math.abs(offset.top);
    $('#posX').text('x: ' + xPos);
    $('#posY').text('y: ' + yPos);
    },
   stop: function(event, ui) {
    $(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#dragThis').click(function() { 
    $.blockUI({ message: $('#loginForm') }); 
    setTimeout($.unblockUI, 2000); 

   }); 
    }); 



    // Show dropped position.



    var Startpos = $("#dragThis").position();
    var Stoppos = $(this).position();
    $("#dragThis").val((Stoppos.left - Startpos.left));
    var left = Math.abs(Stoppos.left);
    var top = Math.abs(Stoppos.top);

    $('#posX').text('left: ' + left);
    $('#posY').text('top: ' + top);





}


});
```

This is the pic of an image with its xy coordinate, I want when the image drag in any way then drop, then a popup message will appear...How to do??help please....

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might like the results better if you used jQuery UI and their [Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) behavior, but if that's not an option, or overkill, it's pretty trivial to create and absolutely position an element.

Here is an example that, when you click the link in the center of the page, a DIV with a message is displayed roughly centered in the viewport: http://jsfiddle.net/HackedByChinese/ZxCUb/5/

Comment: I'm sorry..but is there other way to display popup message??

Comment: If you can explain what you don't like about my answer I can perhaps help you better.

Comment: ok...Actually I want to display a pop up message after getting the position of the image..in my pop up message, I want to insert a text box...Any ideas on how I want to do that? Please help me...I had used alert message or prompt message but I dont know how to add textbox in them..

Comment: I updated my example code to show you what I meant more clearly. Basically my code to display a dialog, you'd adapt after you get your image position.

Comment: ok,that's what I want...But now, I don't know how to match in my coding...I want when once I get my image xy coordinate, immediately the pop up message will come out...How can I insert your code in my code that I've post?help me...

Comment: I wanted to integrate your example code into my fiddle, but I don't have the markup. Based on what you've said so far, presumably you'd add it in your `stop` function you supplied to `draggable`. I'll try updating my example

Comment: please help me by updating your code...n please see my edit post....I've insert picture...

Comment: wow! that's great! but how I want to do if once the image drag and the pop up message come out, the image itself cannot move anywhere.?How to do that? Hope u will help because I'm new here..tq..

Comment: You'd like to disable drag and drop after the popup is displayed?

Comment: yes...how to do? and in the popup message has cancel button...when user click cancel button,then the image can be drag n drop as usual...

Comment: ok...but u didn't get what I mean.I mean that when drag image then popup came out, the image itself will not move...the cancel button just for cancel the location name..please help me..tq

Comment: can u help me please...how to placed the pop up message out of the box??